# Applying function to every other column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below code which rounds every column in my dataframe:

```
def column_round(decimals):
    return partial(pd.Series.round, decimals=decimals)

df = df.apply(column_round(2))
```

I'd like to do this to every other column, in a new dataframe that I have.  I believe i read somewhere that `::` is a built in notation for stepping, but i'm not quite sure how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
df[df.columns[::2]].apply(column_round(2))
```

This steps over the df columns so you can sub-select them

Example:

```
In [2]:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('abcdefgh'))
df

Out[2]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]
Index: []

In [3]:
df.columns[::2]

Out[3]:
Index(['a', 'c', 'e', 'g'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Please post representative data, code and desired output we can only answer questions based on your posted question

Comment: nvm, figured it out.  will delete my comment